# passing class object between 50...60 files

Tags: c++, file, oop, struct, instance

I writing OOP software with C++ that i need pass instances of my classes between files, 50...60 files. Unfortunately , I used a library that uses a callback function and not an object.

**Question:**
I used a few sates such as struct between cpp files, but i got `multiple definition` error or ... How do I pass ONE instance from each class between 50...60 classes?

```
Class A{}; A *instanceA = new A();
Class B{}; B *instanceB = new B();
.
.
.
Class Z{}; Z *instanceZ = new Z();
```

I need to pass intaanceA, intanceB and so on between files.  Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you defined the instance in a header file and included that in multiple files:

`A.h`:

```
class A{};

A* instanceA = new A();
```

`b.cpp` and `c.cpp` both `#include <A.h>`, causing multiple definition error.

To correct you can use `extern` to *declare* the instance in the header file and *define* it in exactly one `.cpp` file:

`A.h`:

```
class A{};
extern A* instanceA;
```

`A.cpp`:

```
A* instanceA = new A();
```

---

Another cause is using `extern` in the header file but defining `instanceA` in multiple `.cpp` files (as was the case here).

Comment: @seg_fault, can you post the header file where `instanceA` is declared.

Comment: `class AudioCallbackData
{
public:
    AudioCallbackData();

    class1 *socketPtr;
    class2 *mainCorePtr;
    class3 *audioCorePtr;
    class4 *devPtr;
    class5 *audioMixer;
};
extern AudioCallbackData  *audioCallbackDataPtr;`

Comment: then i defined two cpp files : `AudioCallbackData *audioCallbackDataPtr = new AudioCallbackData() `  ,but  then changed to  `AudioCallbackData *audioCallbackDataPtr` but in two state i got `multiple definition.`

Comment: Only define it in one `.cpp` file. All `.cpp` files will share that instance.

Comment: Ok, i get good result : my mistake: i defined in every `cpp file`. and i should define in one `cpp file`.